# ejabberd server logs show accepted connection but xmpp client shows no response from server

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

I recently setup ejabberd server on macos X 10.7. The server seems to be running fine and admin page is accessible via internet using http://abc.example.com:5280/admin.

I installed "simple XMPP client", "ChatSecure" and other xmpp chat client in my android phone to connect to my ejabberd server. All of them failed. When I try to connect, I can see following line in ejabberd logs

```
2015-07-29 23:28:58.380 [info] <0.573.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.7250>) Accepted connection 182.70.123.139:55402 -> 192.168.1.4:5280
2015-07-29 23:37:51.844 [info] <0.571.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.7277>) Accepted connection 182.70.123.139:10751 -> 192.168.1.4:5222
```

however, login times out on xmpp chat client. Not sure what's causing this issue. When I install similar xmpp clients on the same box where ejabberd server is running and try to connect using bob@abc.example.com , it works fine.

The issue is only coming when I use some remote machine or phone. Login doesn't work even though request is reaching to ejabberd server.

Please help

---

Updated post after below suggestion from raymond

Hi, Raymond

Here is the updated logs post debug mode. It is stuck at last line. Please suggest.

```
2015-07-30 21:16:46.450 [info] <0.566.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299    (#Port<0.7012>) Accepted connection 1.39.10.237:46913 -> 192.168.1.4:5222
2015-07-30 21:16:46.889 [debug] <0.586.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:349 Received XML on stream = <<"<stream:stream to=\"abc.example.com\" xmlns=\"jabber:client\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" version=\"1.0\">">>
2015-07-30 21:16:46.889 [debug] <0.587.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1901 Send XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='129956901' from='abc.example.com' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>">>
2015-07-30 21:16:46.890 [debug] <0.587.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1901 Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:features><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='5m6LdO+13BLJZeS37oD5PF54bGY='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>">>
```

when I try to connect using xmpp client on the same machine as ejabberd is running, its working and below is log snippet of it.I am not getting "Auth" line when I try to connect using remote machine or android device over internet.

```
2015-07-30 21:47:46.149 [info] <0.566.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.7017>) Accepted connection 182.70.123.139:55949 -> 192.168.1.4:5222
2015-07-30 21:47:46.150 [debug] <0.617.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:349 Received XML on stream = <<"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n<stream:stream to=\"abc.example.com\" xmlns=\"jabber:client\" xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" version=\"1.0\">">>
2015-07-30 21:47:46.150 [debug] <0.618.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1901 Send XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='1273758616' from='abc.example.com' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>">>
2015-07-30 21:47:46.152 [debug] <0.618.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1901 Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:features><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='5m6LdO+13BLJZeS37oD5PF54bGY='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>">>
2015-07-30 21:47:46.156 [debug] <0.617.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:349 Received XML on stream = <<"<auth xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\" mechanism=\"DIGEST-MD5\">dXNlcm5hbWU9ImFkbWluIixyZWFsbT0iY2hhdC52b3Rlc3VwLmNvbSIsbm9uY2U9IjM3OTYwNjcwNDYiLGNub25jZT0iQitjNDNpZkZ1d3NvN2JzYXRrMGRGT3N6dDJNTGhrZ2o3YkF2bWJGVyt3Yz0iLG5jPTAwMDAwMDAyLHFvcD1hdXRoLG1heGJ1Zj02NTUzNixkaWdlc3QtdXJpPSJ4bXBwL2NoYXQudm90ZXN1cC5jb20iLHJlc3BvbnNlPWE0Nzg1MTc2ZGE0MzdkOWYyNzBmMjhmODc5ZmZhYjQx</auth>">>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection is just slow (timeout), it could be because of carrier slowing down the traffic on port 5222.

To validate this hypothesis, you should:

- Use ejabberd debug log level to see if the negociation is progressing (even slowly).
- Try to connect on port 5223 in pure SSL to see if it faster.
- Try to run ejabberd on another port like 443 that is unlikely to be slowed down by your mobile provider.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't copy logs showing that connection attempts made on 5222 is also showing  same log statement however, xmpp client is saying no response from server. I updated original post now. Please help

Comment: updated original question with some more debug log info. is 5223 port need to be open. I try telnet abc.example.com 5223, it says connection refused. but when I try telnet abc.example.com 5222, it works. is response from server stuck due to it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should try changing ejabberd configuration to use another port.

Comment: Ejabberd gets stuck at line mentioned above. It does not have auth stanza in logs

Comment: Before auth stanza there should be stream open. Maybe you trying to use ssl on clear socket or the reverse.

Comment: How can I check the issue? Should I go thru ejabberd configuration and change something there?

Comment: No, this is likely a client configuration issue.

Comment: it was indeed issue of client where I was trying to connect to server on non-SSL port using SASL connection. Thanks a lot Remond.